# Django Migrations - what benefits do they bring?

Tags: python, django

I am pretty sure that [Django Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) bring many benefits to the Django platform. I am just having a hard time identifying those benefits.

Maybe someone could explain to me in what circumstances Django Migrations can be beneficial. In what way does it benefit the work of a software developer?

I could not find that kind of information in the documentation. Maybe it is so obvious that there is no need.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any hint.

**Edit:** My apologies for not being accurate enough. The way I wrote above I appear to imply that Django Migrations do not do anything valuable, which is not what I intended.

I know that Django Migrations are meant to keep the database in sync with my Models. What I find annoying is that, sometimes, things go wrong and I have to reset the migrations manually. Still, after your replies I believe I have a better understanding why the Django Migrations are the way they are.

Comment: They... migrate your database.

Comment: The sql changes, running migration updates changes to DB.

Comment: How would you keep databases in sync with your model definitions without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as your code changes over time, so does your database layout. Models get new fields, your App gets new models etc.

Your code can be changed and uploaded to your server, replacing old files.

Your database however needs to persistent. You cannot just overwrite your database with a different one and ask 10.000 users to sign up again if you decide your user model needs a new field. Also, every developer in your team has their own database on their machine. The schema of these databases need to be in sync.

Migrations allow you to change your database in a controlled way: Any change you make to your database will be represented in a migration and may be "played back" on a different machine. Some migration systems also support both up and down migrations, allowing migrations to be played forward and backwards (order matters!).

The fact that migrations are part of your codebase makes it easy for them to version tracked and shipped using your usual code deployment method.

Before migrations Django allowed to "sync" your model with your database. This enabled some non-destructive changes in your database. However more complex scenarios in which certain operations need to be done during sync could not be achieved.

Migrations, being Python code, on the other hand allow for custom code to be run during a migration. This allows much more flexible and finely controlled changes in your database.

Comment: I think that one problem, which probably contributes to the OP's confusion, is the term "migrations". Outside Django, I've only met this term in a context like "migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL", or "migrating from Windows to Linux". I think the term "[database] upgrade" would have been better.

Comment: They are actually called "Schema migration". Laravel, Rails, Django, they all abbreviate it to "migration".

Comment: Thanks for this info. "Schema upgrade" sounds much more accurate in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The migrations make it easy to maintain database updates.

You control the database through Django models. E.g. Add a field to one of the models.

Then you can make migrations and migrate and these changes will be replicated in your SQL database by the addition of this field.

Answer (score 0):

You make some changes to your database, you:

- Change the default value of a field
- You update all user entries so that their "name" field begins with a capital letter
- You remove a model altogether

So now you need to modify your database schema, get to it!

Chances are you haven't bothered to learn how to write SQL yet so you need to do that first... oh and then its sensitive data you're dealing with so you need to make sure you don't make any mistakes when your deleting that table (Bobby tables much?)..

This doesn't sound fun at all, and its error prone. Especially as you hire new people and then you need to make sure they don't delete EvilCorps data by mistake.

So, instead you opt for the framework that abstracts all these operations into a language that you write anyway, that you store within your source control, tagged to the developer that committed them.

So whats the benefit to the developer? Time and abstraction - the benefits of which I hope are obvious.